# Bot identification with slash command in direct message channel

Tags: java, bots, slack, slack-api

I have custom slack bot called 'rbot'. Also I created a custom slash command '/r-out'. whenever this command is being executed from any channel, my java service is being called with parameters included 'channel_id' and 'channel_name', which I use to identify from which channel this command is being executed.

Now, I want to restrict this command for 'rbot' only. For which, I need to validate if command is being executed as in a direct message channel with 'rbot' or not. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify that a slash command was sent in a direct message channel with your app you just need to check that the `channel_id` in the slash request refers to a valid direct message channel of your app.

In more detail:

When a user executes your slash command in a direct message channel with your app your app will receive a slash request like this: (PHP array)

```
array (
  'token' => 'XXX',
  'team_id' => 'T12345678',
  'team_domain' => 'mydomain',
  'channel_id' => 'D12345678',
  'channel_name' => 'directmessage',
  'user_id' => 'U12345678',
  'user_name' => 'erik.kalkoken',
  'command' => '/evestatus',
  'text' => '',
  'response_url' => 'https://hooks.slack.com/commands/Txxx',
  'trigger_id' => '123',
)
```

The `channel_id` will start with "D" indicating that this comes from a direct message channel.

Next pull the list of direct message channels for your app with [`im.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/im.list). Make sure to use your app token, so you get the direct message channels for your app.

If the `channel_id` is in that list, then the slash command was used in a direct message channel with your app.

Comment: I have couple of questions regarding "im.list", it seems that, channelId starting with 'D' will be different for every user in workspace, even if they communicate to single bot 'rbot'. If new user joins in workspace, new ID will be generated. Is it also possible that, channelId gets modified for same user and bot ('rbot') pair?